# Is there a API (like dup) to duplicate fstream so it can

Tags: c, linux

I want to write a stream into one FILE *fp at the same time the stream should be copied onto another fp too is there a better way to write my debug function by eliminating one fprintf?

```
const int logflag=1;
#define debug(args ...) if (logflag) { FILE *flog = fopen("test.log", "a+"); fprintf( flog, args); fclose(flog); } fprintf(stderr, args); 

int main()
{

    debug("test"); // writes test into both stderr and flog 
    debug("test2");
}
```

Comment: This seems better handled from the command line.  Print out logs and let Linux handle the rest: `./prog 2>&1 | tee f.log`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, it's two different file pointers and you can only write to one at a time.  Actually, `dup` still doesn't help you because it closes the duplicated file descriptor:

```
"dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary"

from the dup2 man-pages
```

However, if your goal is to have both a log to the screen and to a file, you are better served by using the tools Linux already provides you.  A generally good practice (I don't remember the source for this) is to have a program print its output and debugging to a `stdout`/`stderr` and let the calling user determine how to handle the output.

Following this, if all of your output goes to `stderr`, you can do the following when executing the program:

```
$ ./program 2>&1 | tee file.log
```